# Session Replay vs Session Fixation vs Session Hijacking

Tags: security, session, session-hijacking, session-fixation, session-replay

Can anyone give a clear difference between session fixation, session replay and session hijacking attacks? I have read many articles, but the matter is still unclear between session hijacking and session replay attacks.

Comment: What is your current understanding and where specifically you are unclear?

Answer (score 9):

Both fixation and hijacking have ultimately the same goal - gaining access to a session. They only differ in how you achieve that.

Session hijacking is simply the act of *stealing* an existing, valid session cookie. Most commonly through sniffing network traffic (a MITM attack), but also through any other ways that a session ID may be leaked.

Session fixation is similar, but inverted - a pre-defined session cookie is *planted* into the victim's browser. So after the victim logs into a website, they will use the same session cookie that the attacker already knows, and thus the attacker-owned cookie is now authenticated and can be exploited.
Of course that requires an attacker to have temporary access to the victim's browser itself, but the principle is very simple - there's no need to steal the data if it is under your control in the first place.

Replay is a bit different and can mean two things ...

If the attacker *already* has access to a session cookie (via fixation or hijacking), then it's just the act of reusing the cookie for whatever they want.
Otherwise, it can refer to tricking the victim into re-submitting a previously valid request (with the same session cookie). For example, a user could be tricked into buying multiple quantities of a good that they only wanted a single unit of.

*Note: I've used "session cookie" everywhere to simplify the explanations, but of course there are other means of transferring session IDs.*

How to protect yourself against these attacks:

- Use TLS (HTTPS) to prevent MITM attacks and thus the most common ways of hijacking. Also set the `Secure` flag on cookies, to prevent them being submitted over a plain-text connecition (i.e. browsers will only send when using the `https://` scheme).
- Set the `HTTPOnly` flag on cookies, so that e.g. JavaScript doesn't have access to the cookie. If JS can't access cookies, that also means it can't leak them (can't be hijacked), but there's lots of other ways to exploit client-side code.
- Regenerate session IDs on every privilege-changing action a user performs (login, logout, login as admin - if there's an extra form for that), as well as on regular, short time intervals. This serves as a mitigation mechanism against *all* of the 3 attacks.
- Have your application reject session cookies that don't match a server-side record, to prevent fixation.